# Setup react.js with Node.js using Typescript

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I am new here and I need help!
I'm not able to find a WORKING guide for setting up a Typescript project using React.ja and Node.js. I spent hours on searching online tutorials but I've only lost time,as the stuff I foud was not clear at all, or I just have some errors in my machine.
Anybody can give me some clarifications?
Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

Use the official Create React App utility with Typescript template. [Check This Link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#creating-a-typescript-app)

**EDIT**

You can use some well-built starter boilerplates, with [Yeoman](https://yeoman.io/generators/).
It will save you a lot of time.

Comment: This will create only a client side app. I need to connect node too